# Access to HDFS Oozie java action with Kerberos

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, kerberos, oozie

I have developed Java application to connect to Ldap server and get the details in csv format based on user arguments. The result csv file will be saved in HDFS (Hadoop File system).

In order to write to HDFS, I have imported `org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation` and set the Kerberos configuration properly. Below are the code snippet.

```
config.set("hadoop.security.authentication","Kerberos");
UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(config);
UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(Principal,KeyTabfile);
```

we kept the keytab file in edge server of the POC environment. When I run the Java application from edge server, It is reading the keytab file running fine and writing the results to HDFS.

But my issue starts when I tried to shedule this application using oozie. Oozie will launch java actions in any of the data nodes in a cluster based on the availability of resources and oozie cant access the edge server. Because of this, my java action in oozie getting failed with security exception since it cant read the keytab file in edge server.

Below is exception details.

```
java.io.IOException: Login failure for hdfs://namenode:8020 from keytab xxxxx@zz.yy.COM: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty nameString not allowed
at sun.security.krb5.PrincipalName.validateNameStrings(PrincipalName.java:171)
at sun.security.krb5.PrincipalName.<init>(PrincipalName.java:393)
at sun.security.krb5.PrincipalName.<init>(PrincipalName.java:460)
at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:650)
at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:617)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(UserGroupInformation.java:967)
at RunLdap_Utility.ldapLookupLoop(RunLdap_Utility.java:142)
at RunLdap_Utility.main(RunLdap_Utility.java:72)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.run(JavaMain.java:56)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:47)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.main(JavaMain.java:35)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:241)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1709)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
```

Kindly suggest me the solution for this issue

Comment: Did you try to remove that *ad hoc* UGI invocation from your code and **just use the default authentication happen**? -- i.e. on the Edge Node, create the Kerberos ticket beforehand with `kinit`; and inside an Oozie workflow, just let Oozie request a YARN container *with a proper Hadoop delegation token* (which gives transparent access to HDFS).

Comment: Also, look into the Oozie documentation for "Credentials". These are necessary for Hive, HBase etc. that do not rely on delegation tokens, and require raw Kerberos auth.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter It worked. Thanks!